# Java Swing: Set starting time on timer and loop it

Tags: java, swing, time, timer, set

i'm using this [example on leepoint.net](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/examples/animation/41TextClock/25textclock.html)

with this code the timer starts on real time seconds, but i was wondering how i can make it
start at 1 second and then let it run up to 10 seconds and start over?
So from 1 to 10 and so on..

```
class ClockListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            _timeField.setText(String.format("%1$tS", now));

                    }
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) (with logical & consistent indentation).

Comment: thank you for your comment i'll keep that in mind for next questions, sorry for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class ClockListener implements ActionListener {
    int count = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fakeSecond = (count++ % 10) + 1; 
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int h = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int m = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        _timeField.setText("" + h + ":" + m + ":" + fakeSecond);
    }
}
```