# Incrementing a value in a JTextField with a timer

Tags: java, time, jformattedtextfield

How do I go about making a timer that will increment the time in a JFormattedTextField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

This lets you execute an ActionListener repeatedly in the Swing event thread with a specified delay.

The just get and set the value from the textfield.

Edit: not a Runnable but an ActionListener

Comment: Speedy response. That probably means I was googling poorly. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be accurate to do a Thread.sleep for (1000) and then just have it update the field with a second added?

Comment: No, you generally don't want to use a Thread.sleep() as that will block your UI in the meantime. If you just want to call it once, call timer.setRepeats(false).

Comment: Ahh. I just read that link and it's simple and seems to be perfect, thanks.

Comment: +1 `javax.swing.Timer` is a good choice for this. See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528939/java-swing-two-classes-where-to-put-if-statements-and-new-actionlisteners/5529043#5529043).