# Changing the picture of a Buffered Image?

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

I was wondering how you can switch the picture being loaded into a buffered image when an action is called?

For example, if the buffered image is currently loading "Hand.png", I want to be able to press a button or a key, and have it load "Foot.png" instead. My action listeners and buffered image are set up correctly, I'm just unsure of the syntax required to change a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: You may be looking for `setPressedIcon()`; here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4170233/230513) using `setRolloverIcon()`; see also [`ButtonGroupTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513), which uses a `JToggleButton`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

don't change the image, create several images and display different images depending on events/actions