# Error while using swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, runtime-error, imageicon

I'm trying to create panel with some button which would enables disable the other button
What's the problem with the codes its compiled perfectly but while running shows the error.
I'm not able to debug this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: buttondemo (wrong nam
e: components/buttondemo)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:472)
```

Here's the code

```
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class buttondemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public buttondemo() {
        ImageIcon Left = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\nco\\Desktop\\Swing\\components\\images\\left.png");
        ImageIcon Right = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\nco\\Desktop\\Swing\\components\\images\\right.jpg");
        ImageIcon Middle = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\nco\\Desktop\\Swing\\components\\images\\middle.jpg");
        b1 = new JButton("Disable middle button", Left);
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);// shortcut D
        b1.setActionCommand("disable");
        b2 = new JButton("middle button", Middle);
        b2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
        b2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);// shortcut M
        b3 = new JButton("Enable middle button", Right);
        b3.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.RIGHT);
        b3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);// shortcut E
        b3.setActionCommand("enable");
        b3.setEnabled(false);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setToolTipText("click on the middle button to " + "disable middle");
        b3.setToolTipText("click on the middle button to " + "enable middle");
        b2.setToolTipText("click disable");
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("disable".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b1.setEnabled(false);
            b3.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL img = buttondemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (img != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(img);
        } else {
            System.err.println("could not find path" + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button demso");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buttondemo Contentpane = new buttondemo();
        Contentpane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(Contentpane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It appears that Java is expecting this class to reside in the components package, but either it does not, or its not been executed from the correct context (path location)

Comment: When did the error occur? At loading time or at button click?

Comment: while running in prompt

Comment: Class file is also in component package sorry i just forget to add package components while pasting code in my code its specified

Comment: A stab in the dark: Do you build a jar file, or just run the class files? If you run the class files, are the class files and package directories named as expected? Windows should not care for upper or lower case, but I seem to remember issues in some scenarios. (like building on a network share.) Does removing the complete build directory help?

Answer (score 2):

- `b3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);// shortcut M` is code line to the non_initalized `JButton` (initialized in the next code line)
- not all [combinations for Text and Icon can be matched together](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/MovingtheIconinaJButtonComponent.htm), without an exceptions from AbstractButton
- use only [constants for BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class buttondemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public buttondemo() {
        Icon Left = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
        Icon Right = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        Icon Middle = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
        b1 = new JButton("Disable middle button", Left);
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
        b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);//shortcut D
        b1.setActionCommand("disable");
        b2 = new JButton("middle button", Middle);
        b2.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        b3 = new JButton("Enable middle button", Right);
        b3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);//shortcut M
        b2.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.EAST);
        b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        b3.setActionCommand("enable");
        b3.setEnabled(false);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setToolTipText("click on the middle button to " + "disable middle");
        b3.setToolTipText("click on the middle button to " + "enable middle");
        b2.setToolTipText("click disable");
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("disable".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b1.setEnabled(false);
            b3.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL img = buttondemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (img != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(img);
        } else {
            System.err.println("could not find path" + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button demso");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buttondemo Contentpane = new buttondemo();
        Contentpane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(Contentpane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

Java6 on WinXP caused the with same exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JButton/ButtonDemo Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JButton.ButtonDemo
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) Could not find the main class: JButton.ButtonDemo.  Program will exit.
>   Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

- but have to use the proper `private` to use instead of `protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {` caused a.m. exception

@see

```
private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL img = ButtonDemo.class.getResource(path);
    if (img != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    } else {
        System.err.println("could not find path" + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `JToggelButton` in a `ButtonGroup`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513).

Comment: I am also using win7 but your code is also showing same error