# Create a Swing component based on another but with different API

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create a new Swing JComponent based on an existing one, but with a different API. In other words, I don't want to extend the existing component, because I don't want it's API to be accessible.

Here an example to clarify my needs:

A replacement of the `JCheckBox` which show two buttons ON/OFF. This could be based on a *pre-configured* `JCommandButtonStrip` (some info [here](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/flamingo/learn.html)) but exposing exactly the same API of `JCheckBox`. The configuration of the `JCommandButtonStrip` must not be altered.

What is the best approach for such a problem?

**Clarifications:**

As someone pointed out, what I wrote about API is not clear.

Of course `JComponent` have a number of public fields and methods which will be available for each sub-class. Then each sub-class of `JComponent` may add its own public fields and methods. For example, `AbstractButton` adds the `isSelected()` method, while `JCommandButtonStrip` adds the `getButtonCount()` method.

So, what I meant is: I want to create a new `JComponent` sub-class `MyJComponent`, which is based on an existing one `ExistingJComponent`. I don't want the public methods of `ExistingJComponent`, except those of `JComponent`, to be exposed by my class `MyJComponent`. Then I want to add some public methods to `MyJComponent`.

Please note that I'm not looking for an alternative to the `JCommandButtonStrip`/`JCheckBox` example. I'm interested in a general approach to such a problem.

Comment: you can't reduce the scope of methods, so once a method in ExistingComponent is public it needs to be public in MyComponent as well (and comply to its contract!). So the answer is: don't waste your time on impossibilities :-)

Comment: @kleopatra your comment would be correct if `MyComponent` extended `ExistingComponent`. But that's not what I asked. `MyComponent` shall **encapsulate** `ExistingComponent`.

Comment: I think either @Charlie's answer,@trahsgod's example [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035834/composing-swing-components-how-do-i-add-the-ability-to-add-actionlisteners/6036048#6036048) and my own example cover exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: okay, so I misunderstood the _is based_ - then one answer is to extend JComponent, c&p most of ExistingComponent (and its ui delegate, one for every LAF that needs to be supported) and hook the new component into the LAFs .. But why in frozen hell would you want to waste time in re-inventing a well-designed and well-tested wheel?

Comment: @kleopatra c&p is something that I really want to avoid. I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I want to customize it.

Comment: _I want to customize_ that's no reason for hiding (inherited) public api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new class which extends JComponent then inside the constructor insert a checkbox into itself.

```
public class MyCoolCheckbox extends JComponent{
    private JCheckBox checkbox;
    public MyCoolCheckbox(String label) {
        checkbox= new JCheckBox(label);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(checkbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

This is obviously incomplete and you may need to delegate certain methods to the child. It might get messy. IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA will generate all this for you if you hit alt-ins (by default) then delegate, then select the checkbox member and pick the entries you want to delegate. For example:

```
public void setForeground(Color fg) {
    checkbox.setForeground(fg);
}

public void setBackground(Color bg) {
    checkbox.setBackground(bg);
}
public Color getForeground() {
    return checkbox.getForeground();
}

public Color getBackground() {
    return checkbox.getBackground();
}
```

Keep in mind that because the child is within the Swing component tree, other code will have access to the children even though they are marked private.

```
((JCheckBox)myCoolCheckbox.getComponents()[0]).setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? What shall I do with the checkbox?

Comment: Do with it what you want, you indicated you wanted to wrap the checkbox component but not expose it's API.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie, that's much more clear now! But which methods shall I forward to the delegate?

Comment: It depends on what functionality of the contained checkbox you want to expose. If you want a consumer of your control to be able to change the text, you will need to delegate the setText method. You would probably also want to delegate all the correlating get methods.

Comment: Shall I also forward any `JComponent`'s method?

Comment: Any that you think are important. The ones related to size might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513), you can use two instances of `JToggleButton` in a `ButtonGroup` to "show two buttons <kbd>ON</kbd> / <kbd>OFF</kbd>." The `ButtonGroup` causes only *one* button in the group to be selected at a time. The following change is illustrated:

```
private final JLabel label = new JLabel(" \u2713 ");
```

[image]

Comment: The three answer are quite different, i think i didn't understand the question.

Comment: I've just edited the question, hope it's now more clear

Comment: Sadly, no; to the extent that inheritance breaks encapsulation, I'm not sure of a "general approach to such a problem," except via delegation; this answer really only addresses the "two buttons" aspect of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this picture of `JCommandButtonStrip`:

[image]

I think you are looking for [JToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) as @trashgod suggested, but I'm not sure about buttons group given the current description of your "problem". If you need buttons group then use it.

Anyway my answer points to this line:

> This could be based on a pre-configured `JCommandButtonStrip` (some info
>   here) but exposing exactly the same API of `JCheckBox`.

Once again it's not clear if you're trying to do a buttons bar such as `JCommandButtonStrip` or you want to do something else. However you can make your own component extending from [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and delegate only those methods that are needed from the outside. For example let's say you want to do a buttons bar such as `JCommandButtonStrip`. Then you can have:

- One class extending from `JComponent`: your buttons bar.
- Another one providing an API to add "commands" to the buttons bar.

***Note***: There's already a [JToolBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) component which can perfectly be used without reinvent the wheel. The example below is just to show you that you can control the API offered to the developers.

#### MyCommandBar.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MyCommandBar extends JComponent {

    private final JPanel content;
    private final Map<String, CommandItem> map = new HashMap<>();

    public MyCommandBar() {
        super();
        content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        content.setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(content);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics graphics = g.create();
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    public void addCommandItem(String actionCommand, CommandItem commandItem) {
        if(map.get(actionCommand) != null) {
            removeCommandItem(actionCommand);
        }
        content.add(commandItem.getComponent());
        map.put(actionCommand, commandItem);
    }

    public void removeCommandItem(String actionCommand) {
        CommandItem commandItem = map.get(actionCommand);
        if(commandItem != null) {
            content.remove(commandItem.getComponent());
            content.revalidate();
            content.repaint();
            map.remove(actionCommand);
        }
    }

    public CommandItem getCommandItem(String actionCommand) {
        return map.get(actionCommand);
    }

    public static class CommandItem {

        public static final int TOGGLE_BUTTON_STYLE = 0;
        public static final int CHECK_BOX_STYLE = 1;
        public static final int DEFAULT_BUTTON_STYLE = 2;

        private final AbstractButton component;

        public CommandItem(String text, boolean state, Icon icon, int style) {
            switch(style) {
                case TOGGLE_BUTTON_STYLE : component = new JToggleButton(text, icon, state); break;
                case CHECK_BOX_STYLE : component = new JCheckBox(text, icon, state); break;
                    default: component = new JButton(text, icon);
            }
        }

        protected AbstractButton getComponent() {
            return component;
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            component.addActionListener(listener);
        }

        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            component.addChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void setAction(Action action) {
            component.setAction(action);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example of use

This code snippet shows how `MyCommandBar` class should be used:

```
MyCommandBar commandBar = new MyCommandBar();
commandBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
commandBar.addCommandItem("BOLD", new MyCommandBar.CommandItem("<html><b>Bold</b></html>", true, null, MyCommandBar.CommandItem.TOGGLE_BUTTON_STYLE));
commandBar.addCommandItem("ITALICS", new MyCommandBar.CommandItem("<html><i>Italics</i></html>", false, null, MyCommandBar.CommandItem.CHECK_BOX_STYLE));
commandBar.addCommandItem("UNDERLINE", new MyCommandBar.CommandItem("<html><u>Underline</u></html>", false, null, MyCommandBar.CommandItem.DEFAULT_BUTTON_STYLE));
```

And you'll see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create `MyJComponent` subclass of `JComponent` with a private field that references a forwarding class for `ExistingComponent`.
 
The interactions with `ExistingComponent` are done with the forwarding class through methods of `MyJComponent`, and you are free to add more methods to `MyJComponent`. 
Please see *Effective Java* item 16, for the delegation pattern used with the forwarding class.

Comment: This sounds exactly like my answer.

Comment: @Charlie: it sounds a bit different to me. If I understood correctly @dawww's answer, he proposes to forward all the `JComponent` public methods from `MyJComponent` to the delegate `ExistingComponent`. While you suggested to add a `ExistingComponent` as a child of the `MyJComponent` container and forward only the methods "_that you think are important_".

Comment: So the difference is all vs important? You can't forward all, for example the Component.getParent() and JComponent.setUI() methods. You probably wouldn't want to waste time delegating all the methods either, JComponent.getInheritsPopupMenu() or any of the deprecated methods.