# How to make a list of JLabel's act as a button group?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, javax

[image]

As you can see in this picture all the characters are selected but I want it differently. I want it to act as a radio button, for example when I click one character all other characters should be deselected.

Comment: You might put them in a `JList` with single selection enabled. Getting the horizontal layout is easy, but the exact layout and look might be tricky.

Comment: Also consider `JToggleButton` with `Icon` in a `ButtonGroup`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22643334/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a if statement to Disable or make all rest of the labels invisible as soon as any one of them is selected.