# showOptionDialog selected option to drawString

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drawstring

I have a `JLabel` inside of a `JPanel` and when I input some message into the `showOptionDialog` and select the "OK" button, the `JLabel` should print out the message I entered. However, the codes I have doesn't even go into the `paintComponent()` method in my `TextLabel` class (I used a simple trace statement to check this). I have also tried adding a new `MouseListener` to my `tagPanel` but it still doesn't work.

My program code is too lengthy so I have only show the codes that are relevant.

**Main Class:**

```
//...list of global variables

public void go()
{       
    //...other codes

    image = new DrawLabel();
    imgPanel.add(image);
    imgPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    image.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());

    text = new TextLabel();
    tagPanel.add(text);
    tagPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    tagPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 480));

    frame.add(imgPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(tagPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

**showOptionDialog in MouseHandler Class:**

```
String[] options = {"OK"};
JPanel popOut = new JPanel();
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Enter keywords: ");
JTextField txt = new JTextField(50);
popOut.add(lbl);
popOut.add(txt);
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, popOut, "Tag", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);

if(selectedOption == 0)
{
    String entered = txt.getText();
    String[] parts = entered.split(", ");

    for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
    {
        keywords.add(parts[i]);
    }

}
else
{
    System.out.println("untitled");
}
```

**TextLabel Class:**

```
private class TextLabel extends JLabel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(keywords != null)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            String words = "";

            for(int i=0; i<keywords.size(); i++)
            {
                words = words + keywords.get(i) + ", "; 
            }

            int fontSize = 20;
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            g.drawString(words, 50, 50);
            repaint();

            System.out.println("here");
        }
        else
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)Where you initialize `keywords`? 2) Don't call `repaint();` inside `paintComponent()`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: repaint() shouldnt be in paintComponent

Comment: Don't extend `JLabel` for this; use `setFont()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513).