# How to add 2 images to the left and right of button?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a button that has 2 (or more) images inside (left and right of button). I researched but have not idea. Can you help me?

Comment: search Google... please post what you have tried so for..

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: do you want the images on the button or beside the button?

Comment: @BevynQ: images on the button, BevynQ.

Comment: You could always create a transparent image then draw one icon to the right, one to the left, and the button 'text' as a string in between.  But really, what is the point of this non-standard (and therefore not 'path of least surprise') GUI component for the end user?

Comment: direct way is to add two JLabels with Icons to JButton, by using BoderLayout to add one to EAST, 2nd to WEST area, then you must little bit to play with visibility of the JButtons text

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513) uses two buttons to alter one image

Answer (score 0):

use this code for every button

```
JButton left_btn = new JButton(new ImageIcon("image_address"));
JButton right_btn = new JButton(new ImageIcon("image_address"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/). It is a custom `Icon` that allows you to combine two icons into one. So you can combine two `ImageIcons` into one. Then you add the `CompoundIcon` to the button.