# How to separate listener of 2 buttons but the same model

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 button and they are the same model. I want to mouse hover a button, another button is highlight. It 's OK. But, when I click a button, the listener of 2 buttons is active. How to active listener of the button that is clicked ?

```
Jbutton A, B; 
A.addActionListener(lnA);
B.addActionListener(lnB);
ButtonModel bm = previewButton.getModel();
arrow.setModel(bm);
```

Comment: Don't use the same model

Comment: No, I want to still use model..@@

Comment: Then check the source in the ActionEvent parameter and base response depending on the source.

Comment: The problem is, as Hovercraft has pointed out, when the model is triggered, then both buttons fire since they rely on the same state as each other. The listeners are actually registered with the model, not the buttons

Comment: `I want to mouse hover a button, another button is highlight.` - then use a MouseListener, not the same model.

Comment: @camickr : How to create background that look like when user hover a normal button.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30722745/230513) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/230513). What's the [real problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)?

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo, you invoke the `setRollover(...)` method of the `ButtonModel` for the button. I still don't understand your real question. Why do you want to change the rollover of two buttons when the mouse is over one button?

Comment: @camickr : when use serRollover(..) and setbackgroud(..). But I can not get color as well as shadow, hightlight... look like style of a normal button on swing