# GUI components of a memory game

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I am working on a homework so i am not asking for code, i am trying to make this by myself. by the way, i am stuck again with the GUI part and have little problems with code part. first things is about button size and image size. i didnt use methods for size of buttons just set the image as an icon for the button. but as you see below, buttons dont fit the image.

[image]

second thing is how can i first disable the icon and when user presses to button it will reveal the icon *?. and how can i embed 8 pictures in a loop*? can i create an array for images... i appreciate if you can help me. and thanks anyway : )

Comment: I think that you could post http://sscce.org/,

Comment: i couldn't find any place for post this. however i will continue to search. and thanks anyway : )

Comment: Edit your question to include your [sscce](http://sscce.org/); I've added related links in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867087/gui-components-of-a-memory-game/7867721#7867721).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with [*How to Use Buttons*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). [`JToggleButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) works well for this, as you can change the `Icon` in an `ItemListener` based on the button's `selected` state. Examples may be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#tbeg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528939/java-swing-two-classes-where-to-put-if-statements-and-new-actionlisteners/5529043#5529043).