# Holding jbuttons in array from e.getsource

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public int open=0;
private JButton  opens[]=new JButton[1];

  for( i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for (j=0; j<buttons[i].length;j++){ 
                n=i*buttons.length+buttons[i].length;
                buttons[i][j]=new JButton();

                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            opens[open]=(JButton) e.getSource();
            if((pressedButton.getIcon() == null)){
                pressedButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/2.jpg")));
                open=open++;
            } else {   
                //pressedButton.setIcon(null);
            }

            }
        if (open==1){
            opens[0].setIcon(null);
            opens[1].setIcon(null);
        }
    }
```

I want to hold 2 clicked `JButton` and then close or stay open. How can i hold in array or something else?

My array holding is wrong?

With this code, i can open unlimited images and none of them is getting closed.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Probably one of the most unclear questions I've read on `SO`.

Comment: I am trying to hold 2 images in array, then it will close them if they are not same. It is a memory game. Only 2 images can be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to hold 2 images in array, then it will close them if they
>   are not same. It is a memory game. Only 2 images can be opened

- load Images to local variables as [Icon/ImageIcons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), to avoids any FileIO meaning code line `pressedButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/2.jpg")));`
- add this `Icon/ImageIcons` to [JButton.setPressedIcon(myIcon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29),
- then there is useless code line to reset `Icon` back with `pressedButton.setIcon(null);`

Comment: Also consider `JToggleButton`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867721/230513).