# Adding A Timer To Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

Well I'm Sorry For Posting More Than One Question In A Short Amount Of Time But I Am Trying To Have This Time Count Down From 3 To 0... Here's My Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClickingGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JButton startbutton, clickingbutton, timerstop;
    static JLabel timelabel, scorelabel;
    static int time = 3;
    static JTextField entertime;
    static Timer clock;
    static Timer countdown;
    static int score = 0;

    public ClickingGame() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        startbutton = new JButton("Start CountDown");
        timelabel = new JLabel("Time Left = NULL", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        entertime = new JTextField();
        clickingbutton = new JButton("Click Here!");
        scorelabel = new JLabel("Score = NULL", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        timerstop = new JButton("Stop Timer!");
        clock = new Timer(1000, this);
        countdown = new Timer(1000, this);

        add(entertime);
        add(startbutton);
        add(timelabel);
        add(scorelabel);
        add(clickingbutton);
        add(timerstop);
        clickingbutton.setEnabled(false);
        timerstop.setEnabled(false);
        startbutton.addActionListener(this);
        clickingbutton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void openGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Clicking Game");
        ClickingGame contentpane = new ClickingGame();
        frame.setContentPane(contentpane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == startbutton) {
            startbutton.setEnabled(false);
            clickingbutton.setEnabled(true);
            time--;
            if (time > 0) {
                countdown.start();
                timelabel.setText("Starting In: " + time);
            } else {
                countdown.stop();
                time = 3;
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == clickingbutton) {
            score++;
            scorelabel.setText("Score = " + score);
        }
    }
}
```

As You Can See I Have My Timer "countdown" Set Up Right, It Only Counts Down Once... I Am Trying To Get It To Count Down All The Way To 3...

Comment: See also this [`ClockExample`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529043/230513).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a case in your `actionPerformed` for your `countdown` object as the source.

EDIT:

you could try something like this:

```
 if (e.getSource() == startbutton) {
        startbutton.setEnabled(false);
        clickingbutton.setEnabled(true);
        if (time > 0) {
            countdown.start();
            timelabel.setText("Starting In: " + time);
       }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == countdown){
        timelabel.setText("Starting In: " + time);

        if (time == 0) {
            countdown.stop();
            time = 3;
        } else {
            time--;
        }

    }
```

Comment: how would i go about doing that?